# Group columns if coordinates are not more distant than a threshold

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
Sps       Gps start  end
SP1       G1      2    322
SP1       G1    318   1368
SP1       G1  21125  22297
SP2       G2      2    313
SP2       G2    334   1359
SP2       G2  11716  11964
SP2       G2  20709  20885
SP2       G2  21080  22297
SP3       G3      2    313
SP3       G3    328   1368
SP3       G3  21116  22294 
SP4       G4    346   1356
SP4       G4  21131  22282
```

and I would like to add a new columns `Threshold_gps` for each `Sps` and `Gps` that have start and end next to each others but where the distance length (end-start) is below a threshold of `500.`

Let's take examples:

---

**SP1-G1**

```
Sps       Gps start  end
SP1       G1      2    322
SP1       G1    318   1368
SP1       G1  21125  22297
```

here `318-322=-4` which is `< 500` so I group them

```
Sps       Gps start  end    Threshold_gps
SP1       G1      2    322  G1
SP1       G1    318   1368  G1
SP1       G1  21125  22297
```

then, `21125-1368=19757` which is `> 500` so I do not group them

```
Sps       Gps start  end    Threshold_gps
SP1       G1      2    322  G1
SP1       G1    318   1368  G1
SP1       G1  21125  22297  G2
```

---

**SP2-G2**

```
Sps       Gps start  end    Threshold_gps
SP2       G2      2    313
SP2       G2    334   1359
SP2       G2  11716  11964
SP2       G2  20709  20885
SP2       G2  21080  22297
```

`334-313=21` which is `< 500` so I  group them

```
Sps       Gps start  end    Threshold_gps
SP2       G2      2    313  G1
SP2       G2    334   1359  G1
SP2       G2  11716  11964
SP2       G2  20709  20885
SP2       G2  21080  22297
```

then, `11716-1359=10357` which is `> 500` so I do not group them

```
Sps       Gps start  end    Threshold_gps
SP2       G2      2    313  G1
SP2       G2    334   1359  G1
SP2       G2  11716  11964  G2
SP2       G2  20709  20885
SP2       G2  21080  22297
```

then, `20709-11964=8745` which is `> 500` so I do not group them

```
Sps       Gps start  end    Threshold_gps
SP2       G2      2    313  G1
SP2       G2    334   1359  G1
SP2       G2  11716  11964  G2
SP2       G2  20709  20885  G3 
SP2       G2  21080  22297
```

then, `21080-20885=195` which is `< 500` so I group them

```
Sps       Gps start  end    Threshold_gps
SP2       G2      2    313  G1
SP2       G2    334   1359  G1
SP2       G2  11716  11964  G2
SP2       G2  20709  20885  G3 
SP2       G2  21080  22297  G3
```

---

and so on..

```
Sps       Gps start  end    Threshold_gps
SP1       G1      2    322  G1
SP1       G1    318   1368  G1
SP1       G1  21125  22297  G2 
SP2       G2      2    313  G1
SP2       G2    334   1359  G1
SP2       G2  11716  11964  G2
SP2       G2  20709  20885  G3 
SP2       G2  21080  22297  G3
SP3       G3      2    313  G1
SP3       G3    328   1368  G1
SP3       G3  21116  22294  G2
SP4       G4    346   1356  G1
SP4       G4  21131  22282  G2
```

Does someone have an idea please?

Here is the dict format of the tab if it can helps:

```
{'Sps': {0: 'SP1', 1: 'SP1', 2: 'SP1', 3: 'SP2', 4: 'SP2', 5: 'SP2', 6: 'SP2', 7: 'SP2', 8: 'SP3', 9: 'SP3', 10: 'SP3', 11: 'SP4', 12: 'SP4'}, 'Gps': {0: 'G1', 1: 'G1', 2: 'G1', 3: 'G2', 4: 'G2', 5: 'G2', 6: 'G2', 7: 'G2', 8: 'G3', 9: 'G3', 10: 'G3', 11: 'G4', 12: 'G4'}, 'start': {0: 2, 1: 318, 2: 21125, 3: 2, 4: 334, 5: 11716, 6: 20709, 7: 21080, 8: 2, 9: 328, 10: 21116, 11: 346, 12: 21131}, 'end': {0: 322, 1: 1368, 2: 22297, 3: 313, 4: 1359, 5: 11964, 6: 20885, 7: 22297, 8: 313, 9: 1368, 10: 22294, 11: 1356, 12: 22282}}
```

Comment: the wording is a bit misleading as some of them are not overlapping; you are more interested in the difference between end and start for subsequent rows been less than 500

Comment: yes some of them do not overlapp indeed, I will update the description sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you might want:

```
df['Threshold_gps'] = (df
   .groupby(['Sps', 'Gps'], group_keys=False)
   .apply(lambda d: (s:=d['end'].shift().rsub(d['start'])
                     .gt(500))
                     .cumsum().add(1-s.iloc[0])
                     .astype(str).radd('G')
         )
)
```

for python <3.8:

```
def get_group(g):
    s = g['end'].shift().rsub(g['start']).gt(500)
    return s.cumsum().add(1-s.iloc[0]).astype(str).radd('G')

df['Threshold_gps'] = (df
   .groupby(['Sps', 'Gps'], group_keys=False)
   .apply(get_group)
)
```

Output:

```
    Sps Gps  start    end Threshold_gps
0   SP1  G1      2    322            G1
1   SP1  G1    318   1368            G1
2   SP1  G1  21125  22297            G2
3   SP2  G2      2    313            G1
4   SP2  G2    334   1359            G1
5   SP2  G2  11716  11964            G2
6   SP2  G2  20709  20885            G3
7   SP2  G2  21080  22297            G3
8   SP3  G3      2    313            G1
9   SP3  G3    328   1368            G1
10  SP3  G3  21116  22294            G2
11  SP4  G4    346   1356            G1
12  SP4  G4  21131  22282            G2
```

Comment: Hi thanks but it does not group as it should be looking at the expected result...

Comment: @chippycentra you're right, see the update

Comment: I get a SyntaxError: invalid syntax showing  the ```(s:=d[``` part

Comment: @chippycentra this requires python 3.8+, for earlier version you'd have to use a custom function (let me know)

Comment: oh, and is there an alternative using python3.7 ?

Comment: Hello mozway. May I ask what is the application of `:=` in `apply(lambda d: (s:=d['end'].shift().rsub(d['start'])`?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR this is the walrus operator, (assignment expression) this enables to assign and return a value

Comment: So you used it so that you can use `s` further down your pipeline?